# Creating Configuration object inside doGet method of servlet giving me Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String name=req.getParameter("name");
    String email=req.getParameter("email");
    int marks=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("marks"));

    Student st=new Student(0,name,email,marks);

    System.out.println("Inside get method before configuration object generation");
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
    System.out.println("After configuration initialization");
    cfg.configure("Resourses/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    System.out.println("after giving hibernate config file");
    sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();

}
```

and I am getting this error in output

inside init method
after calling super
**Inside get method before configuration object generation**

```
Sep 25, 2016 8:56:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Controller.StudentRegistrationServlet] in context with path [/StudentRegistration] threw exception
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createClassLoader")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default Java Runtime Security setting does not allow the run time permission 'createClassLoader', which is required by the ArcSDE Java API.

Update the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security\java.policy` **file**.
 Add the following lines to the **java.policy file** inside default permissions "grant ... { ... }" block :

```
Code:
// default permissions granted to all domains
grant {
     permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "NLS_LANG", "read";
     //....rest of code as it is. 
     }
```

**Note**  The servlet container may have its own security policy that overrides the JRE-wide policy. For example, Tomcat uses the one in `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/catalina.policy`, not the file that vou've been modifying.

For **Tomcat** server add permissions in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\catalina.policy file next to WEB APPLICATION PERMISSIONS as shown below:

```
// ========== WEB APPLICATION PERMISSIONS =====================================
grant {
     permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "NLS_LANG", "read";
     //....rest of code as it is. 
     }
```

Comment: I added these lines in java.policy file but still getting the same error.It was not giving this error while I was using hibernate only i.e. this same code outside my servlet methods.

Comment: put the code in grant block in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security**java.policy** file.

Comment: I put these lines in both java.policy and catalina.policy but still getting the same error.

Comment: Where have to declared sf (SessionFactory) in the code? please add the entire servlet code.